# How to play after clicking a button somewhere else?

Tags: jwplayer

I have an ad that displays when the video is paused. Then what I want is that when the button is clicked, this ad dissappears and the video resumes. This is what I have so far.

```
<span onclick="closeAndPlay;" class="close-play"> x </span> 

function closeAndPlay() {
        var adDiv = document.getElementById('ad-div');
        console.log('test');
        if (adDiv) {
            adDiv.parentNode.removeChild(adDiv);
        }
    }
```

But haven't figured out the part where the video plays

Comment: Are you running a VAST ad, or did you just put your own div over the player as the "ad"?

Answer (score 1):

You can use javascript api to display the ad.

```
jwplayer().onPause(function(){/*display ad*/})
```

Add to your closeAndPlay()

```
function closeAndPlay() {
    /*your function to hide ad*/"
    jwplayer().play(); //resume video
    }
```